# How to return hiccup as a list/vector

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am passing a vector of hiccup to a funtion that just wraps it in more hiccup, but it does not return it as I would expect.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
(defn wrap-fn 
  [input]
  [div.content-box
    [input]])

(defn main-fn 
  [vector-of-hiccup]
  (foreach [hiccup from vector-of-hiccup]
    (wrap-fn hiccup-from-list)))
```

How do I implement the made up foreach loop above?

I've tried to use 'apply' to apply the wrap-fn to each of the vector params but it only returns the first element wrapped. I've tried to creating all sorts of loops and I have similar levels of success.

I'm sure there is a way to do this, please help me find one that works.

Comment: `(map wrap-fn list-of-hiccup)`  ?

Comment: You should probably add more details including examples of desired before/after behavior to get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
(defn wrap-fn
  [input]
  [:div.content-box
   [input]])  ; <= you may not want to wrap `input` in a vector.

(defn main-fn
  [vector-of-hiccup]
  (vec
    (for [item vector-of-hiccup]
      (wrap-fn item))))
```

Note the `:` in `:div`.  Hiccup vectors always start with a keyword.  Also, since `for` returns a lazy sequence, you should convert it into a vector with `vec`.

Also, depending on your situation, you may want to have `input` instead of `[input]` under the `:div.content-box`.

See [the Documentation section](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) of the [clj-template](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template)  project for valuable learning information.